# How to Wrap a Text Inside A Merged Cell

Tags: tables

I am having trouble to put some texts inside a merged cell. This is the code for the table.

```
\begin{table}
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Solute in\\ Measurement\\ Number\end{tabular}}} & \textbf{PNR} & \textbf{PRL} & \textbf{TPL} & \textbf{PMT} & \textbf{AMT} & \textbf{HXP} \\ \hline
\multirow{3}{*}{\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Area\\ Under\\ Each\\ Peak\\ (mAu$\cdot$min)\end{tabular}}} & 1 & 212.47839 & 1041.35779 & 851.02411 & 755.29639 & 802.65906 & 371.62747 \\ \cline{2-8} 
 & 2 & 213.23718 & 1045.07227 & 858.31976 & 757.09601 & 807.86127 & 353.14246 \\ \cline{2-8} 
 & 3 & 213.71013 & 1047.04382 & 858.27057 & 762.12048 & 809.55322 & 365.25497 \\ \hline
\multirow{3}{*}{\textbf{Ratio}} & 1 & 0.57175103 & 2.8021550 & 2.2899925 & 2.0324019 & 2.1598486 & 1 \\ \cline{2-8} 
 & 2 & 0.60382764 & 2.9593504 & 2.4305198 & 2.1438827 & 2.2876356 & 1 \\ \cline{2-8} 
 & 3 & 0.58509849 & 2.8666107 & 2.3497848 & 2.2164058 & 2.2164058 & 1 \\ \hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textbf{Average}} & 0.58689239 & 2.8760387 & 2.3567657 & 2.0876095 & 2.2212966 & 1 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}%
}
\end{table}
```

Below is what it is produced.
[image]

Can anyone be able to help me put the phrase "Area Under Each Peak (mAu*min)" inside its cell here? (I know that the font is Times New Roman, but it doesn't matter what font I use anyway. And yes, each word is entered as seen because I still want to stick with this text size.)

Comment: I think the words should fit in the cell if you don't add the ``\\`` after "Area" and "Each", and just keep those after "Under" and "Peak".

Comment: Well, it works. I guess this problem is solved. Thanks a lot, Vincent.

Comment: It is amazing how people love so much jail the data. But maybe it should be considered "criminal information" because the number of decimal places `:)` Well, seriously, please take a look to https://inf.ethz.ch/personal/markusp/teaching/guides/guide-tables.pdf

Comment: Don't use `resizebox`to mak a table fit into the textwidth. It will lead to inconsistent font sizes. Please also make your example code compilable by adding the documentclass as well as the relevant packages.

Answer (score 2):

Three possible versions of your table. Since there was no MWE given, I gad tu guess a documentclass.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\normalsize\bfseries}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{geometry}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{5.9pt}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\thead{Solute in\\ Measurement\\ Number}} & \thead{PNR} & \thead{PRL} & \thead{TPL} & \thead{PMT} & \thead{AMT} & \thead{HXP} \\ 
\hline
\textbf{Area Under} & 1 & 212.47839 & 1041.35779 & 851.02411 & 755.29639 & 802.65906 & 371.62747 \\ \cline{2-8} 
\textbf{Each Peak} & 2 & 213.23718 & 1045.07227 & 858.31976 & 757.09601 & 807.86127 & 353.14246 \\ \cline{2-8} 
\textbf{(mAu$\cdot$min)} & 3 & 213.71013 & 1047.04382 & 858.27057 & 762.12048 & 809.55322 & 365.25497 \\ \hline
 & 1 & 0.57175103 & 2.8021550 & 2.2899925 & 2.0324019 & 2.1598486 & 1 \\ \cline{2-8} 
\textbf{Ratio} & 2 & 0.60382764 & 2.9593504 & 2.4305198 & 2.1438827 & 2.2876356 & 1 \\ \cline{2-8} 
 & 3 & 0.58509849 & 2.8666107 & 2.3497848 & 2.2164058 & 2.2164058 & 1 \\ \hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\thead{Average}} & 0.58689239 & 2.8760387 & 2.3567657 & 2.0876095 & 2.2212966 & 1 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}%
\end{table}


\begin{table}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\normalsize}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{cccccccc}
\toprule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\thead{Solute in\\ Measurement\\ Number}} & \thead{PNR} & \thead{PRL} & \thead{TPL} & \thead{PMT} & \thead{AMT} & \thead{HXP} \\ 
\midrule
{Area Under} & 1 & 212.47839 & 1041.35779 & 851.02411 & 755.29639 & 802.65906 & 371.62747 \\  
{Each Peak} & 2 & 213.23718 & 1045.07227 & 858.31976 & 757.09601 & 807.86127 & 353.14246 \\ 
{(mAu$\cdot$min)} & 3 & 213.71013 & 1047.04382 & 858.27057 & 762.12048 & 809.55322 & 365.25497 \\ \midrule
 & 1 & 0.57175103 & 2.8021550 & 2.2899925 & 2.0324019 & 2.1598486 & 1 \\ 
{Ratio} & 2 & 0.60382764 & 2.9593504 & 2.4305198 & 2.1438827 & 2.2876356 & 1 \\  
 & 3 & 0.58509849 & 2.8666107 & 2.3497848 & 2.2164058 & 2.2164058 & 1 \\ \midrule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\thead{Average}} & 0.58689239 & 2.8760387 & 2.3567657 & 2.0876095 & 2.2212966 & 1 \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}%
\end{table}


\begin{table}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\normalsize}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{rcccccc}
\toprule
  & \multicolumn{6}{c}{\thead{Solute in Measurement Number}}\\
  & \thead{PNR} & \thead{PRL} & \thead{TPL} & \thead{PMT} & \thead{AMT} & \thead{HXP} \\ 
\midrule
\multicolumn{7}{@{}l}{Area Under Each Peak (mAu$\cdot$min)}\\
  1 & 212.47839 & 1041.35779 & 851.02411 & 755.29639 & 802.65906 & 371.62747 \\  
  2 & 213.23718 & 1045.07227 & 858.31976 & 757.09601 & 807.86127 & 353.14246 \\ 
  3 & 213.71013 & 1047.04382 & 858.27057 & 762.12048 & 809.55322 & 365.25497 \\ 
\multicolumn{7}{@{}l}{Ratio} \\
  1 & 0.57175103 & 2.8021550 & 2.2899925 & 2.0324019 & 2.1598486 & 1 \\ 
  2 & 0.60382764 & 2.9593504 & 2.4305198 & 2.1438827 & 2.2876356 & 1 \\  
  3 & 0.58509849 & 2.8666107 & 2.3497848 & 2.2164058 & 2.2164058 & 1 \\ 
Average & 0.58689239 & 2.8760387 & 2.3567657 & 2.0876095 & 2.2212966 & 1 \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}%
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would start by questioning whether any purpose is served by showing 5 to 8 decimal digits in the six data columns. I can't tell for sure, since I don't know what this table is all about. I have a hunch, though, that your readers would be better served if you showed them just 2 or at most 3 decimal digits, *not* 5 or 8.

To reduce the number of digits shown without having to retype all the numbers, it's convenient to use the `siunitx` package, its `S` column type, and its rouding-related options -- see below for an implementation.

With this setup in place, it doesn't seem necessary to go thru any line-wrapping contortions.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\sisetup{round-mode=places,
         round-precision=2,
         table-format=3.2} % set a default col. format

\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} lc 
   S S[table-format=4.2] *{4}{S} }
\toprule
Solute in Measurement & Number &
{PNR} & {PRL} & {TPL} & {PMT} & {PMT} & {HXP} \\ 
\midrule
Area under each peak & 1 & 212.47839 & 1041.35779 & 851.02411 & 755.29639 & 802.65906 & 371.62747 \\ 
\quad(mAu$\cdot$min) & 2 & 213.23718 & 1045.07227 & 858.31976 & 757.09601 & 807.86127 & 353.14246 \\ 
 & 3 & 213.71013 & 1047.04382 & 858.27057 & 762.12048 & 809.55322 & 365.25497 \\
\addlinespace
Ratio & 1 & 0.57175103 & 2.8021550 & 2.2899925 & 2.0324019 & 2.1598486 & 1 \\ 
 & 2 & 0.60382764 & 2.9593504 & 2.4305198 & 2.1438827 & 2.2876356 & 1 \\
 & 3 & 0.58509849 & 2.8666107 & 2.3497848 & 2.2164058 & 2.2164058 & 1 \\ 
\addlinespace
Average & & 0.58689239 & 2.8760387 & 2.3567657 & 2.0876095 & 2.2212966 & 1 \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```